# mySQL - I want to select only the 75 most recent posts unless a column deems the post 'permanent'

Tags: mysql, timestamp, where-clause

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE (
  post != ''
  AND timestamp >= (
    SELECT `posts`.`timestamp`
    FROM posts
    WHERE post != ''
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 75 )
) OR (
  post != ''
  AND authorization = 'permanent'
)
ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC
```

The first WHERE selects the 75 most recent, but the code ignores the ones that supposed to be permanent. I don't know why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: separate them into two queries and then use UNION

Comment: thanks. I keep getting an error when I try to ORDER BY id ASC when I do that.

Comment: got to wrap the whole thing in a select * from (UNION IN HERE ) as A order by A.somecolumn

Comment: Some sample data would help. Try this though...`SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE post != ''
AND (timestamp >= (SELECT `posts`.`timestamp` FROM posts WHERE post != '' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 75) OR authorization = 'permanent')
ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC`  ...I think your parentheses might be to blame. `post != ''` on both side of `OR` seems to be redundant also.

Comment: both of these solutions worked. thanks